# How to go about enabling side scrolling in Wagtail admin site

Tags: django, wagtail, side-scroller

I have been tackling a particular design issue with Wagtail admin. Thus far I have not found a way to enable side scrolling admin listing pages. I want to extend my user model with more data about the users (e.g., occupation, education, address, and so on). While extending Wagtail with some models for a particular project, I noticed Wagtail admin listing pages do not automatically activate sides crolling as Django admin does.

I have looked at Wagtail hooks doccumentation but apparently there isn't a straightforward way to do that. I don't think it would be wise to mess with core css. Does anyone have an idea on how to customize css to enable that?

See pictures below:

This is how Django admin handles it. We can add filters while the table adjusts itself activating side scrolling.

[image]

Wagtail Bakery demo user model has few fields. So the listing admin page does not need to side scroll. I have not tested adding filters on this page yet, but I am assuming it will work just as it did to my other models.

[image]

This is how my admin page looks like when using filters. The table does not activate side scrolling and gets messed up when I use filters.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help poiting the way to best tackle this problem. Thus far I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115382/wagtail-customizing-admin) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816408/wagtail-full-width-admin) answers to similar, though not exaclty the same, problems with Wagtail admin design.

Comment: You might open an issue for this on https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues. It seems something that should be handled in Wagtail. For a quick fix: Django loads the first template it encounters, so you might override the template and add a wrapping div with `overflow-x: auto;`.